# Selenium ClickAndHold doesn't work on new Kendo Chart

Tags: kendo-chart

I've been upgrading my Kendo version recently, and upon the change, one of my tests broke. It tries to select an area over a kendo chart. Previously, it worked just fine. However, with the new Kendo version, the test fails. It lines up the mouse over the beginning and end of where it should be selecting, but it is not selecting anything. Here is the snippet of code that should be selecting the chart area:

```
new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(WebDriverContext.Current)
            .ClickAndHold(zoomToElement).MoveToElement(zoomFromElement)
            .Release(zoomFromElement).Perform();
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue?